# Woocommerce - shortcode custom query in custom tab times out - why?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have been following some online tutorials to create a custom tab in the my-account page from woocommerce. This is all going well, accept for adding a shortcode in the custom tab content.

The code for registering the custom tab is like this:

```
//add new tab to my account

function bbloomer_add_premium_support_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'mijn-elearning', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
  
add_action( 'init', 'bbloomer_add_premium_support_endpoint' );
  
// 2. Add new query var
  
function bbloomer_premium_support_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'mijn-elearning';
    return $vars;
}
  
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'bbloomer_premium_support_query_vars', 0 );
  
// ------------------
// 3. Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu
  
function bbloomer_add_premium_support_link_my_account( $items ) {
    $items['mijn-elearning'] = 'Mijn Elearnings';
    return $items;
}
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'bbloomer_add_premium_support_link_my_account' );
  
// ------------------
// 4. Add content to the new tab
  
function bbloomer_premium_support_content() {
    echo do_shortcode('[dashboard_student]');
}
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_mijn-elearning_endpoint', 'bbloomer_premium_support_content' );
```

the shortcode is defined like this:

```
function dashboard_function($atts = array(),$html = 'test',$name) {
    ob_start();
    $query = New WP_QUERY( array ('post_type'=>'programma','posts_per_page'=>-1,'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'level', 'value'   => 'programma', 'compare' => 'LIKE'),),),);
            while($query->have_posts()){
                $html .= '<li><a href="'.get_the_permalink.'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
            }
  $html .= '</ul>';
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ob_get_clean();
  return $html;
}
add_shortcode('dashboard_student','dashboard_function');

function add_to_init() {
    add_shortcode('dashboard_student','dashboard_function');
}
add_action('init','add_to_init');
```

However, it seems like a query in the custom tab is not possible. It gets stuck and even when i give full access to server memory, i get the fatal error: "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted" (or any higher number).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `the_post()` function.

```
/**
 * Sets up the current post.
 *
 * Retrieves the next post, sets up the post, sets the 'in the loop'
 * property to true.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @global WP_Post $post Global post object.
 */
public function the_post() {
    global $post;
    $this->in_the_loop = true;

    if ( -1 == $this->current_post ) { // Loop has just started.
        /**
         * Fires once the loop is started.
         *
         * @since 2.0.0
         *
         * @param WP_Query $query The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
         */
        do_action_ref_array( 'loop_start', array( &$this ) );
    }

    $post = $this->next_post();
    $this->setup_postdata( $post );
}
```

I revised your code. Try the below code.

```
function dashboard_function($atts = array(),$html = 'test',$name) {
    ob_start();
    $query = New WP_QUERY( 
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'programma',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query'     => array( 
                array( 
                    'key'   => 'level', 
                    'value' => 'programma', 
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $html = '<ul>';
    if( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        while($query->have_posts()){ 
            $query->the_post();
                $html .= '<li><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
        } 
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
  
    ob_get_clean();

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('dashboard_student','dashboard_function');
```

Comment: I can confirm this works. Basically, you added if($query->have+posts()); i have never really understood why this is necessary?

Comment: `if($query->have+posts());` this will check that does query found any posts.

Comment: ah i see now the edit is in $query->the_post()! My bet, thank you!